# How to scale down my retina image on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, retina-display, retina.js

I recently decided to tackle adding retina displayed images to some sites, but when I view them on my iPhone5 they appear huge (although crisp which is nice).  How should I go about reducing the size of my logo?  You can check out my site [here](http://wedgetire.com/)

I'm assuming it's some code I need to edit in my wedge.css file.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Also, not sure if it matters, but I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: Use percentage based widths & heights in your css media queries for mobile, in actuality there's a lot more to it than that though.

Comment: Just a friendly note, the images in your image slider should be compressed...

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall could you provide a link to something that would be able to describe what you're talking about please